# (tensorflow) Am I using two gpus in parallel correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

(I'am sorry if this question is too novice but as I don't quite understand and want to double check whether I am using two gpus in parallel in a correct manner, I ask you the following question.)

Two gpus (with the same model) are installed in the pc I am using. In a pycharm project, I run a tensorflow code setting

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '0'
```

, which then runs with a initial run log

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-09-15 03:36:36.727152: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-09-15 03:36:37.080157: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:17:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.08GiB
2018-09-15 03:36:37.080671: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-15 03:36:37.796088: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-15 03:36:37.796320: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-09-15 03:36:37.796469: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
2018-09-15 03:36:37.796723: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8783 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:17:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

Then in another pycharm project, I run a tensorflow code setting

```
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = '1'
```

which then shows in run log

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
2018-09-15 03:37:00.119630: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2018-09-15 03:37:00.468546: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1405] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:65:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.08GiB
2018-09-15 03:37:00.468930: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1484] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2018-09-15 03:37:01.199726: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:965] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-09-15 03:37:01.199950: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:971]      0 
2018-09-15 03:37:01.200096: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:984] 0:   N 
2018-09-15 03:37:01.200349: I T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:1097] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 8783 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:65:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

What worries me that they have both **device 0**. But their **pciBusIDs** are different.

**So my simple question is am I using two gpus in parallel in a correct manner?**

As I am using Windows 10, I monitored gpu usages with Device Manager, and it seems correct to me. But I just want to hear from experts.

And if it is okay for you to answer, what is pci bus ID, roughly? And why are both of them showing device 0?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to add

```
with tf.device("your_device_name")
```

Just follow this tutorial, section Using Multiple GPUs https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu